# Replacement Screen won't work

Tags: mac

Recently I broke the screen on my 2020 MacBook Air A2337 and replaced it myself. The new screen appears to be entirely black but if you shine light on it you can see the faintest output. I figured the screen was bad so I got a new one and have the exact same issue. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Display settings are normal and not the issue.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I had a similar issue after a flat battery - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458395/85275 Otherwise it could be the ribbon cable incorrectly seated, or broken.